# Python: csv into ifiles by columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with the following structure:

```
Column A: Date (1500 records)

Column A: Layer1 (1500 records)

Column B: Layer2 (1500 records)

Column C: Layer3 (1500 records)

Column D: Layer4 (1500 records)
```

I would like to split the file into four new ones so that the new files has just two columns (and its records obviously): `Column Date + Column Layer`. So in the case of the example:

```
File Record1.csv: Date + Layer1

File Record2.csv: Date + Layer2

File Record3.csv: Date + Layer3

File Record4.csv: Date + Layer4
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants us to write code for him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample code to try

```
import csv
import json

a = open("t.csv", "r")
wa1=open("Record1.csv", "w")
wa2=open("Record2.csv", "w")

wr1 = csv.writer(wa1, dialect='excel')
wr2 = csv.writer(wa2, dialect='excel')

fieldnames = ("Date","Layer1")
reader = csv.DictReader( a, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    wr1.writerow([row["Date"]])
    wr2.writerow([row["Layer1"]])

wa1.close()
wa2.close()
```